# Openlayers 3 - Interaction and pointermove

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to activate an interaction when the mouseover is inside some feature.

It is working so so... the problem is if you move your mouse slowly the interaction keep active.

Is it a bug on OL3, or should I do in a different way?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/gmaq54dm/3/

```
olMap.on("pointermove", function (e) {
    if (e.dragging) {
        return;
    }
    var map = e.map;
    console.log(e.pixel);
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
      return feature;
    });
    var hit = (feature) ? true : false;
    console.log(hit);
    olDraw.setActive(hit);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a bug. You could report the core developers about it.

Comment: I'd wrap the last line in a `setTimeout` call so it gets called after the pointermove event is handled: `window.setTimeout(function() { olDraw.setActive(hit); }, 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in your application, not in OpenLayers. You need to make sure you only hit-detect features from your vector layer, not from the draw layer. Change your `forEachFeatureAtPixel` function to

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
  return feature;
}, null, function(layer) {
  return layer == vectorLayer
});
```

The last argument adds a layer filter to only hit-detect features on the vector layer.

Updated, working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmaq54dm/4/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jonatas, it seems to be a bug.

Though, there is a workaround which seems to do your job.

1. Avoid multiline string. It makes it more complicated for ol3 to verify when your mouse is over the feature.
2. Use `vectorSource.forEachFeatureInExtent(` and then create a small rectangle using mouse coordinates and adding a couple of meters on every direction. This will make sure your mouse "mbr" is falling within the features. 
   Please notice that I use +-5meters from mouse coordinate to built the mbr. You have to adjust to satisfy your requirment.

check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/wyy4voms/)